# Load Data Transfert files v2 into Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to insert all our DT files v2 into BQ. 
I already did it with the click file, I spotted any trouble.

But it's not the same game with the activity and impression.

I wrote a quick script to help me in making the schema for the insertion :

```
import csv,json
import glob
data = []

for i in glob.glob('*.csv'):
  print i
  b = i.split("_")
  print b[2]
  with open(i, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1 = next(reader)
  title = [w.replace(' ', '_').replace('/', '_').replace(':', '_').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '').replace("-", "_") for w in row1]
  print title

  for a in title:
    j={"name":"{0}".format(a),"type":"string","mode":"nullable"}
    print j
    if j not in data:
      data.append(j)

  with open('schema_' + b[2] + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

After that, I use the small bash script to insert all our data from our GCS .

```
#!/bin/bash

prep_files() {
date=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'_' -f4 | cut -c1-8)
echo "$n"
table_name=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'_' -f1-3)
bq --nosync load --field_delimiter=',' DCM_V2."$table_name""_""$date" "$var" ./schema/v2/schema_"$n".json
}


num=1

for var in $(gsutil ls gs://import-log/01_v2/*.csv.gz)
    do
       if test $num -lt 10000
       then
          echo "$var"
          f=$(echo "$var" | cut -d'/' -f5)
          n=$(echo "$f" |  cut -d'_' -f3)
          echo "$n"
          prep_files
          num=$(($num+1))
       else
          echo -e "Wait the next day"
          echo "$num"
          sleep $(( $(date -d 'tomorrow 0100' +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
          num=0
        fi
    done


 echo 'Import done'
```

But I have this kind of error :

> Errors:
>   Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
>   /gzip/subrange//bigstore/import-log/01_v2/dcm_accountXXX_impression_2016101220_20161013_073847_299112066.csv.gz: CSV table references column position 101, but line starting at position:0 contains only 101 columns. (error code: invalid)

So I check the number of columns in my schema with :
`$awk -F',' '{print NF}'`
But I have the good number of column...
So I thought that was because we had comma in value (some publishers are using a .NET framework, that allows comma in url). But theses values are enclosed with double quote.

So I made a test with a small file :

```
id,url
1,http://www.google.com
2,"http://www.google.com/test1,test2,test3"
```

And this loading works...

If someone have a clue to help me, that could be realy great. :)

EDIT : I did another test by make the load with an already decompressed file.

> Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
>   file-00000000: CSV table references column position 104, but line starting at position:2006877004 contains only 104 columns. (error code: invalid)

I used this command to find the line : `$tail -c 2006877004 dcm_accountXXXX_activity_20161012_20161013_040343_299059260.csv | head -n 1`

I get :

`3079,10435077,311776195,75045433,1,2626849,139520233,IT,,28,0.0,22,,4003208,,dc_pre=CLHihcPW1M8CFTEC0woddTEPSQ;~oref=http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/core/bridge3.146.2_en.html,1979747802,1476255005253094,2,,4233079,CONVERSION,POSTVIEW,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,0.000000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

After that : `$head -n1 dcm_account8897_activity_20161012_20161013_040343_299059260.csv | awk -F',' '{print NF}'`

Response : 102

So, I have 104 columns in the first row and 102 on this one...

Anyone else have trouble with the DT files v2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar issue and found the problem was due to a few records being separated by carriage returns into 2 lines. Removing \r solved the problem

The line affected is usually not the line reflected in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

I would open the csv file from google sheets, and compare the columns with the schema you generated.
Most probably you will found a bug in the schema.

Comment: I edited my post with another test. I don't think that the schema. Maybe I am doing wrong with my command line...

Comment: In your added test, the number 102 and number 104 comes from the same csv file, from different rows? I cannot imagine that.

Comment: In your added test, the number 102 and number 104 comes from the same csv file, from different rows? I cannot imagine that.
I guess tail and head command uses \n as new line, however \n can appear inside values in csv.

Comment: In your added test, the number 102 and number 104 comes from the same csv file, from different rows? I cannot imagine that. 
I guess tail and head command uses \n as new line, however \n can appear inside values in csv. 
I also guess the problem might be gone, if you try with other options from "bq load", especially, set "allow_quoted_newlines" to true and skip_leading_rows to 1.

Comment: I will give a try with allow_quoted_newlines for the trouble with url between double quote. but that's not solve the problem with rows with different lenght. I didn't find \n in this csv, so we can't said that's not possible to get 2 differents length

Comment: Please let us know the result. Basically I was saying, because new-line char can be part of value, so result from head & tail might not be a complete row, that's why you saw 102 and 104.
I'm surprised that '\n' is not in the csv -- did you search '\n' as regular expression?

Comment: I used another command line to control what I said. I was wrong, their is no line under 104 columns.